# How to add .h file in library

Tags: library

I am trying to make an ultrasonic distance meter using Arduino. For this I added the ultrasonic library. But on compiling it shows this error "ultrasonic.h
not available". Please tell me how to add this .h file.

Comment: You can literally just create one. Usually they are config files so where you initialise variables etc.

Comment: Unless this is a module that you have installed from somewhere? In which case it should have one already. If not then try putting an empty one in and see what happens.

Comment: How did you add your library ? Have you follow these [steps](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries) shown on the arduino site ?

Answer (score 4):

In you Arduino Sketch folder there is a folder called **Libraries**, create a folder there and put your header file in that folder and restart the Arduino IDE.

For example (PC):

```
Documents/Arduino/Libraries/ultrasonic/ultrasonic.h
```

You can now use it in all your projects.

If you only want to use with a particular sketch, place in in the same folder as you  sketch and restart Arduino IDE.